# Making menu items active on desired page

Tags: hooks

I am creating a custom module for menus through which we can allow individual menu link to be active on desired path/paths. The module interface provides similar functionality as block module's visibility configuration.

I am using [hook_translated_menu_link()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_translated_menu_link_alter/7) to implement the visibility functionality. As I have referred **menu item visibility** module for this, but not getting the desired output. Do i need to implement any other hook for this or I am missing out something. As I have implemented `hook_form_id_form_alter()` for the interface and `mymodule_submit()` for form submit functionality and right now trying out `hook_translated_menu_link()` for visibility functionality.  I also have a database entry for my module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation for `hook_translated_menu_link_alter()` says:

> It is only invoked if `$item['options']['alter']` has been set to a non-empty value (e.g., `TRUE`). This flag should be set using [hook_menu_link_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_menu_link_alter/7).

You need to also implement `hook_menu_link_alter()`.

As said by Lester Peabody, the functionality you want should be already implemented by the Context module. If the functionality it's not exactly what you want, you should implement `hook_translated_menu_link_alter()`, and `hook_menu_link_alter()`.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a way you could make the [Context](http://drupal.org/project/context) module a dependency for your module and hook into the Context module to do this?  [Context](http://drupal.org/project/context) already allows you to do this exact function.  You specify conditions and reactions when those conditions are met, per context.  In your case you would specify particular paths as conditions, and then your reaction would be to simply activate a particular menu item.  I would seriously consider checking it out rather than reinventing the wheel.